# How to fix 'request for member in something not a structure or union' error?

Tags: c, arrays, assembly

When I tried to print out the array members, it gave an error. Actually what I'm trying to do is to simulate a register by creating and naming an array and then print out its content as it performs instructions passed to it. This is my code:

```
    struct REGISTER;
    {
     char opcode[15];
     char regDes[15];
     char regN[15];
     char operand2[15];
     int operand2val;
     char name[5];
    };

    REGISTER registers[16];

    void regOut()
    {
    registers[0].name, "R0";
    registers[0].regDest,"0";
    registers[0].val = 0X0;
    registers[1].name,"R1";
    registers[1].regDest,"1";
    registers[1].val = 0X0;
    registers[2].name, "R2";
    registers[2].regDest,2;
    registers[2].val = 0X0;
    registers[3].name, "R3";
    registers[3].regDest,3;
    registers[3].val = 0X0;
    registers[4].name, "R4";
    registers[4].regDest,4;
    registers[4].val = 0X0;
    registers[5].name,"R5";
    registers[5].regDest,5;
    registers[5].val = 0X0;
    registers[6].name,"R6";
    registers[6].regDest,6;
    registers[6].val = 0X0;
    registers[7].name,"R7";
    registers[7].regDest,7;
    registers[7].val = 0X0;
    registers[8].name, "R8";
    registers[8].regDest,8;
    registers[8].val = 0X0;
    registers[9].name, "R9";
    registers[9].regDest,9;
    registers[9].val = 0X0;
    registers[10].name, "R10";
    registers[10].regDest,10;
    registers[10].val = 0X0;
    registers[11].name, "R11";
    registers[11].regDest, 11;
    registers[11].val = 0X0;
    registers[12].name, "R12";
    registers[12].regDest, 12;
    registers[12].val = 0X0;
    registers[13].name, "R13";
    registers[13].regDest,13;
    registers[13].val = 0X10000;
    registers[14].name, "R14";
    registers[14].regDest, 14;
    registers[14].val = 0X0;
    registers[15].name, "R15";
    registers[15].regDest, 15;
    registers[15].val = 0X0104;

void showRegisters(WORD inst)
{
 char opcode[15];
 char regDes[15];
 char regN[15];
 int i;

 printf( R0: "\n%08X"    R1: "%08X"    R2: "%08X"    R3: "%08X"    R4: "%08X"    R5: "%08X"    R6: "%08X"    R7: "%08X"    R8: "%08X"    R9: "%08X"    R10: "%08X"    R11: "%08X"    R12: "%08X"    R13: "%08X"    R14: "%08X"    R15: "%08X",  registers[0].val, registers[1].val, registers[2].val,   registers[3].val, registers[4].val, registers[5].val,   registers[6].val, registers[7].val, registers[8].val,     registers[9].val, registers[10].val, registers[11].val, registers[12].val, registers[13].val, registers[14].val,  registers[15].val)
}
```

I get this error:

```
"error: request for member 'name' in something not a structure or union
 registers[0].name, "R0";"
```

Comment: WTH is `registers[0].name, "R0";` and alikes??

Comment: Probably you need `strcpy()`.

Comment: `struct REGISTER;` ---> `struct REGISTER`

Comment: And what is `val`? Post the real code.

Comment: Suggestion: `struct REGISTER registers[16] = { {.name="R0", .regDes="0", .operand2val = 0X0},  {.name="R1", .regDes="1", .operand2val = 0X0},.....};`

Comment: I would read up on printf.  printf( R0: "\n%08X"    will not work.  printf takes a format string and one or more parameters.  R0: "\n.." doesn't conform to this.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, change line :

```
REGISTER registers[16];
```

to :

```
struct REGISTER registers[16];
```

Then use `strcpy` to write into `char` arrays of your `struct`s, like this :

```
strcpy(registers[0].name, "R0");
```

Also change lines which try to access field `val`, which does not exist, to something like :

```
registers[0].operand2val = 0X0;
```

Finally, use correct syntax for `printf` :

```
printf( R0: "%d "    R1: "%d"    R2: "%d"    R3: "%d"    R4: "%d"    R5: "%d"    R6: "%d"    R7: "%d"    R8: "%d"    R9: "%d"    R10: "%d"    R11: "%d"    R12: "%d"    R13: "%d"    R14: "%d"    R15: "%d",  registers[0].operand2val, registers[1].operand2val, registers[2].operand2val,   registers[3].operand2val, registers[4].operand2val, registers[5].operand2val,   registers[6].operand2val, registers[7].operand2val, registers[8].operand2val,     registers[9].operand2val, registers[10].operand2val, registers[11].operand2val, registers[12].operand2val, registers[13].operand2val, registers[14].operand2val,  registers[15].operand2val);
```

Comment: The `printf` statement in his `showRegisters` also looks sketchy